# Is there a way to retrieve all the queries in a Business unit using API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to move a data extension to the shared, so I need to update all the running Automation query activities which are referencing this DE.
Instead of manually checking all the query activities, if there is a way to retrieve all the queries with an API call I'd like to try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to retrieve all queries in a BU via API, but I think there is a more efficient way to do this.

If you are looking for those that target it, you can define your filter as:

```
        <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
           <q1:Property>DataExtensionTarget.Name</q1:Property>
           <q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
           <q1:Value>{{yourDE}}</q1:Value>
        </Filter>
```

or if you are looking for those that use it as a reference in the query, you can define the filter as:

```
        <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
           <q1:Property>QueryText</q1:Property>
           <q1:SimpleOperator>like</q1:SimpleOperator>
           <q1:Value>{{yourDE}}</q1:Value>
        </Filter>
```

or a combination of both:

```
        <Filter xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
              <Property>DataExtensionTarget.Name</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
              <Value>{{yourDE}}</Value>
           </LeftOperand>
           <LogicalOperator>OR</LogicalOperator>
           <RightOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
              <Property>QueryText</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
              <Value>{{yourDE}}</Value>
           </RightOperand>
        </Filter>
```

and all together it would be:

```
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>QueryDefinition</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.Name</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>QueryText</Properties>
        <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
              <Property>DataExtensionTarget.Name</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
              <Value>{{yourDE}}</Value>
           </LeftOperand>
           <LogicalOperator>OR</LogicalOperator>
           <RightOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
              <Property>QueryText</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
              <Value>{{yourDE}}</Value>
           </RightOperand>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Comment: This worked. 
Thank you, Gortonington.

Comment: @cdr if this solved your question, please make sure to click on that check mark next to my answer to mark it as such. This will allow it to be easily referenced by anyone else facing the same issue as you.